# Create numpy array based on magnitude of difference between arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I have 2 numpy arrays:

```
import numpy as np
arr_a = np.random.rand(10)
arr_b = np.random.rand(10)
```

I want to create an array which contains `1` in specific position if the difference in magnitude between `arr_a` and `arr_b` is greater than specified percentage (say 30%). Right now, I can create the array which contains `1` if `arr_a` is greater than `arr_b` and `0` otherwise.

```
arr_c = numpy.where(arr_a > arr_b, 1.0, 0.0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you mean the magnitude of the difference relative to `arr_a`, use:

```
import numpy as np 

arr_a = np.random.rand(10) 
arr_b = np.random.rand(10)

arr_c = np.where((abs(arr_a - arr_b)/arr_a) > 0.3, 1, 0)
```

If you want the magnitude of the difference relative to `arr_b`, use:

```
arr_c = np.where((abs(arr_a - arr_b)/arr_b) > 0.3, 1, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a copy of `arr_a` and scale it by the appropriate factor, then use where.